# Updating SQL database with DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

so I have an administration menu item on my application that pulls from my viewModel as the `ItemSource` which is pulled from SQL and added to an `ObservableCollection`.

[Admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZG8T.png)

I would like for it to update the SQL when you press the update permissions button. Here is my `DataGrid`

XAML:

```
<GroupBox  Header="Update User Permissions">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Static model:ViewModel.Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Add Truck" Binding="{Binding CanAddTruck}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Park Truck" Binding="{Binding CanParkTruck}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Load Truck" Binding="{Binding CanLoadTruck}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Admin" Binding="{Binding IsAdmin}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</GroupBox>
<UniformGrid Columns="2" Grid.Row="2">
    <Button Content="Cancel"/>
    <Button Content="Update permissions" Command="{Binding SaveUserDB_Command}" />
</UniformGrid>
```

User Model:

```
public AllUsers()
{
    SaveUserDB_Command = new RelayCommand(SaveUserDB_Command_Execute, SaveUserDB_Command_CanExecute);
}

public AllUsers(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    Name = reader.GetString("Name");
    Username = reader.GetString("Username");
    CanAddTruck = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CanAddTruck"]);
    CanParkTruck = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CanParkTruck"]);
    CanLoadTruck = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CanLoadTruck"]);
    IsAdmin = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsAdmin"]);
}

private string _Name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
}

private string _Username;
public string Username
{
    get { return _Username; }
    set { _Username = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Username"); }
}

private bool _CanAddTruck;
public bool CanAddTruck
{
    get { return _CanAddTruck; }
    set { _CanAddTruck = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CanAddTruck"); }
}

private bool _CanParkTruck;
public bool CanParkTruck
{
    get { return _CanParkTruck; }
    set { _CanParkTruck = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CanParkTruck"); }
}

private bool _CanLoadTruck;
public bool CanLoadTruck
{
    get { return _CanLoadTruck; }
    set { _CanLoadTruck = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CanLoadTruck"); }
}

private bool _IsAdmin;
public bool IsAdmin
{
    get { return _IsAdmin; }
    set { _IsAdmin = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsAdmin"); }
}

public RelayCommand SaveUserDB_Command { get; private set; }

void SaveUserDB_Command_Execute(object param)
{
    Debug.Print("Not Working");
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();
    string query = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Permissions WHERE Username = @user)
                    UPDATE dbo.Permissions 
                    SET CanAddTruck = @addTruck, CanParkTruck = @parkTruck, CanLoadTruck = @loadTruck, IsAdmin = @admin
                    WHERE Username = @user
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO dbo.Permissions(Name, Username, CanAddTruck, CanParkTruck, CanLoadTruck, IsAdmin) VALUES(@name, @user, @addTruck, @parkTruck, @loadTruck, @admin);";

    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addTruck", CanAddTruck);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parkTruck", CanParkTruck);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loadTruck", CanLoadTruck);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", IsAdmin);
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
bool SaveUserDB_Command_CanExecute(object param)
{
    return true;
}
```

View Model:

```
public static void GetUsers()
{
    Users.Clear();

    using var conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();
    string qry = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Permissions";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Users.Add(new AllUsers(reader));
    }
    conn.Close();
}

public static ObservableCollection<AllUsers> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<AllUsers>();
```

Pressing the update permissions button should see all changes in the DataGrid and replicate to the SQL. I would imagine I would need to get the rows values but am lost on how to. Some assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I can't make them.

From you're code it doesn't seems like you have initialized `SaveUserDB_Command`.
There are `SaveUserDB_Command_CanExecute` and `SaveUserDB_Command_Execute` but they are useless if there is not a `RelayCommand` object calling them.

------- UPDATE -------

Since RelayCommand is a class that implements the [ICommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommand?view=netframework-4.8) Interface that you need to implement yourself i'm not sure how you designed the constructor.

Let's suppose it is something like

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)    
{
    this.execute = execute;
    this.canExecute = canExecute;
}
```

You need to initialize `SaveUserDB_Command` like

```
SaveUserDB_Command = new RelayCommand(SaveUserDB_Command_Execute, SaveUserDB_Command_CanExecute);
```

Comment: I have updated the post, that is how I have it right now. Sorry forgot to add that into the code.

Comment: Two things: Have you overridden some parent controls `DataContext`?
Does `SaveUserDB_Command_Execute` execute? Or it's just not being fired?

Comment: Not being fired, I am getting this: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SaveUserDB_Command' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel' (HashCode=2586631)'. BindingExpression:Path=SaveUserDB_Command; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=2586631); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: As you can see from the error it's searching the `SaveUserDB_Command` RelayCommand inside ViewModel, so probably you've set a different DataContext on one of the parents of your button. When you change DataContext for a control, all the control' children will use the same DataContext unless you specify otherwise on that particular child control.

Comment: I tried this Grid.DataContext>
            <model:AllUsers/>
        </Grid.DataContext> on the xaml code above

Comment: Ok so that works, but now the updating am I doing it wrong?

Comment: i would imagine I would need to get the rows values but am lost on how to.

Comment: Now you have to update the Users ObservableCollection. An ObservableCollection updates the control only when an item has been added or removed from it. So during the execution update Users with the correct data. PS. You can't just reinitialize Users with a new ObservableCollection because you will lose the binding and the control will never be updated again

Comment: So calling GetUsers in SaveUserDB_Command_Execute should be enough

Comment: I looked again at your code and I relalized that you are calling the RelayCommand on every AllUsers. I don't that possible, probably only one instance of it get called, I would do a methods that do it outside (like in the ViewModel) and for all the AllUsers at the same time.

Comment: I am calling it in a seperate empty class, update observablecollection, how would that update the SQL?

Comment: No I'm sorry I wrote that because I thought the problem was that the DataGrid wasn't updating on view.

Comment: Do you know how to update the database via the grid?

Comment: You can look at previous questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896923/12730306)

Comment: That is using code behind, I would like to use MVVM

Comment: I'm not too sure myself. In my works I used a NuGet Packet called MvvmLight that 
 have a class called Messenger. This class allow to call methods between different classes without direct references. So with this i could call ViewModel methods from the code behind. As you can see it's not really a solution, but it works. Please rate my answer if it did help you and create a new question so that other people can answer to your new question.